# Template function in a class inside of a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, linker, namespaces

EDIT - SOLVED:

Moving the template function definition to the header file fixed the problem.

Original Post:

Sorry in advance if this is complicated to understand, I tried looking on Google and Stack Overflow for answers but none of them answer my question exactly because I'm not sure what to search for. I have the following class (simplified example):

```
struct MyClass
{
    template <typename T> T* myFunction();
};
```

This function is defined in the corresponding .cpp file as such:

```
template <typename T> T* MyClass::myFunction()
{
    // some code
}
```

This compiles just fine, but then I realized that for an unrelated reason I needed to put this class in a namespace, which led me to the following definition:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    struct MyClass
    {
        template <typename T> T* myFunction();
    }
}
```

And the .cpp file:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    template <typename T> T* MyClass::myFunction()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

After making this change, I got the following error from another file where I was already using this function:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  MyNamespace::SomeClass* MyNamespace::MyClass::myFunction<MyNamespace::SomeClass>(), referenced from:
      MyNamespace::anotherFunction() in anotherFile.cpp.o
```

It looks like this where I am using it in that file:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    void anotherFunction()
    {
        SomeClass* object = anotherObject->myFunction<SomeClass>();
    }
}
```

I think I am misunderstanding something about how template arguments are used. Why does moving my class into a namespace make it not link properly? I made sure to wrap all my files in the correct namespace, so that isn't the issue, and I also made sure that all the necessary header files were imported before the namespace declaration.

Comment: This should work. Can you prepare a [mcve]? Show us the exact file contents (make sure to throw away irrelevant code and re-test after that), and the exact compiler command you run.

Comment: @molbdnilo I thought that too, but apparently not. Adding `<T>` causes a compilation error.

Comment: I really doubt that your first attempt worked if you ever called the function, since [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good idea, I will do that and report back.

Comment: I'm with @molbdnilo.  Put it this way: why *don't* you implement the function in the header file?

Comment: @PaulSanders I suppose if it's a requirement there's no reason to not do that, I had just done it this way because I prefer keeping actual code that runs out of my header files for simplicity and readability.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I made a minimal reproducible example, and it didn't link properly. I then tried defining the function in the header file as people were suggesting, and it worked perfectly. I guess that was the issue. Is there really no way to define it in the cpp file?

Comment: There are ways to define the function in another file and they are *worse* than just doing so in the header.

Comment: Alright, makes sense lol. I will keep it in the header. Thanks all!